# NOT IN returns nothing but LEFT OUTER JOIN returns delta between two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two tables, and there is an expected delta of rows, but this delta does not return when unless I use a left outer join. Can someone help me understand why Query 1 works for this use case but Query 2 does not:

```
--QUERY 1 - THE FIRST QUERY RETURNS THE EXPECTED DELTA BETWEEN FULLPROD and IMPORT_DOCUMENTS AS EXPECTED
SELECT FULLPROD_DOCID
FROM   (SELECT IMPORT_DOCUMENTS.DOCID AS Import_Documents_DocID,
               FULLPROD.DOCID         AS FullProd_DocID
        FROM   FULLPROD
               LEFT OUTER JOIN IMPORT_DOCUMENTS
                            ON FULLPROD.DOCID = IMPORT_DOCUMENTS.DOCID) SUBQUERY
WHERE  IMPORT_DOCUMENTS_DOCID IS NULL  

--QUERY 2 - WOULD EXPECT BELOW QUERY SHOULD RETURN THE SAME RESULT AS QUERY 1 BUT RETURNS NOTHING
SELECT DOCID
FROM   FULLPROD
WHERE  DOCID NOT IN (SELECT DOCID
                     FROM   IMPORT_DOCUMENTS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` returns *no* rows if *any* value in the subquery is `NULL`.

For this reason, I always recommend `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`/`WHERE` for this logic.  They behave more intuitively (although `NOT IN` is technically correct).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `QUERY-2` with this

```
SELECT DOCID
FROM FULLPROD F
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DOCID
                    FROM  IMPORT_DOCUMENTS I
                    WHERE F.DOCID = I.DOCID
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN will not work, even if one NULL value is present in the subquery.

NOT IN like below will convert from:

```sql
WHERE  DOCID NOT IN (SELECT DOCID
                     FROM   IMPORT_DOCUMENTS)
```

To

```sql
WHERE DOCID != (SELECT DOCID FROM IMPORT_DOCUMENTS WHERE DOCID = 1)
AND
DOCID != (SELECT DOCID FROM IMPORT_DOCUMENTS WHERE DOCID = 2)
.
.
```

So, if we get a value where DOCID is null then whole AND condition will fail and no rows are returned.

It is better to go for NOT EXISTS clause like given below:

```sql
SELECT DOCID
FROM   FULLPROD AS fp
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
SELECT DOCID FROM IMPORT_DOCUMENTS AS IMD WHERE IMD.DOCID = fp.DOCID)
```

Read more about [NOT EXISTS Vs NOT IN](https://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/02/18/not-exists-vs-not-in/)

Comment: My upvote doesn't count as I'm new but this was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. No problem